# How to apply AND operator to a python bytes object

Tags: python

I have a 4 bytes value that need to be applied a masking

```
x = b'\x22\x22\x22\x22'
mask = b'\xff\xff\x00\x00'
```

I tried  `x & mask` but show unsupported operand type(s) error.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bytes' and 'bytes'
```

Please advice how I can apply the masking here?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 b"".join([bytes([a & b]) for a,b in zip(x,mask)])
```

result:

```
b'""\x00\x00'
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo Well, `"` in ascii is 34 in decimal which is 0x22 in hex, I just copied the output from IPython

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. But actually I need to convert it back to short int. Maybe just a memoryview()? can you advice? Basically masking masking, I wish to take the first 2 as a uint val_1 and the last 2 as a uint val_2

Comment: @J_yang you can use ```int.from_bytes``` for that - for example: ```int.from_bytes(b'\xff\xff', byteorder='big')``` you can split the ```bytes``` every two bytes in a list for that